# Entity Framework not saving all properties on update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, getter-setter

I am trying to update an entity with custom getters and setters but they are not being saved if I edit any other property on the entity. I have a DTO, which maps onto the retrieved entity.

DTO:

```
public class MyEntityDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Settings { get; set; }

    public virtual string SettingsJson
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Settings); }
        set
        {
            Settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Update Function:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(dto MyEntityDto)
{
    var existingEntity = await _myRepository.GetByIdAsync(dto.Id);

    existingEntity.Name = dto.Name;
    existingEntity.Enabled = dto.Enabled;
    existingEntity.Settings = dto.Settings;

    await _myRepository.Update(existingEntity);

    // save changes happens at end of request
}
```

What happens is my `SettingsJson` does not get updated. I have stepped through it and `existingEntity.SettingsJson` and `existingEntity.Settings` both have the correct data. `Name` and `Enabled` do get updated.

However if I remove the assignments for `Name` and `Enabled`, `SettingsJson` does get updated.

It does work however on entity creation, just not on update. I would also like to point out I do not have access to `DbContext`.

Comment: I notice in your entity class all have been declared as virtual except for the dictionary object.

Comment: @bilpor EF doesn't support dictionaries anyway so it wouldn't be stored in the DB.

Comment: What's `QueueSettings`?

Comment: @RuudLenders Sorry just meant to say `Settings`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I'm guessing Entity Framework doesn't know it should update `SettingsJson` in the database because you never modify it directly in your code. Yes, you modify the `Settings` object which is used in the getter of `SettingsJson`, but Entity Framework does not track objects that way.

   Try this after modifying the `Settings` object, but before doing the actual update:

   ```
   _myDbContext.Entry(existingEntity).Property(e => e.SettingsJson).IsModified = true;
   ```

   This code however assumes your `DbContext` is exposed, which may not be the case.

EDIT:

2. **If you don't have access to the `DbContext`**, you must directly set the `SettingsJson` property in order to have Entity Framework update it in the database. I understand that in your current implementation you never need to worry about updating both the actual dictionary and the JSON representation of the dictionary, but that's just not possible with Entity Framework. You'll have to try something like this:

   ```
   public virtual string SettingsJson { get; set; } // just an auto-implemented property

   ...

   existingEntity.Settings = dto.Settings;
   existingEntity.SettingsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto.Settings);
   // save changes
   ```
3. **Another solution** could be to directly set the `SettingsJson` in the setter of `Settings`, like so:

   ```
   private Dictionary<string, string> settings // private backing field
   public Dictionary<string, string> Settings
   {
       get { return settings; }
       set
       {
           settings = value;
           SettingsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto.Settings); // EF tracks this
       }
   }
   ```

   *However*, if you add elements to the dictionary after setting it, you need to re-serialize the dictionary again, in order to update the JSON string. You could solve this dynamically by using some sort of observable dictionary, but make sure it only serializes the dictionary once, when needed (before calling updating the database).
4. This is not really a solution but it's food for thought. Databases don't understand dictionaries. You know that, that's why you're using JSON to help you out. However, why not simply add a `Setting` table to your database model?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I do not have access to the context. So if I never directly modify the property in code, how does it save it successfully on a create? Is that different?

Comment: @KevinLee Yeah create is different. When inserting a new record, Entity Framework receives an object that is not tracked by the context. It doesn't know which properties were set and which weren't, so it will use them all when inserting. When updating EF relies on tracking which is why it doesn't understand `SettingsJson`. See my updated answer for workarounds if you don't have access to the context.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers. I understand what's happening now.